# How to convert string to string array in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, string

**Well, I have a function that takes a string array as input...**

**I have a string to process from that function...**

So,

```
Dim str As String = "this is a string"

func(// How to pass str ?)

Public Function func(ByVal arr() As String)
     // Processes the array here
End Function
```

I have also tried:

```
func(str.ToArray)  // Gives error since it converts str to char array instead of String array.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you want it turned into an array? Delimited by spaces?

Comment: No.. nothing like that.. Simply convert "mystring" to an array with array with single element "mystring".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With VB10, you can simply do this:

```
func({str})
```

With an older version you'll have to do:

```
func(New String() {str})
```

Answer (score 5):

Just instantiate a new array including only your string

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s As String = "hello world"
    Print(New String() {s})
End Sub

Sub Print(strings() As String)
    For Each s In strings
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That works.. **but can we do it in a neater way.. ?**
Something more intuitive like `str.ToStringArray` or something ?

Comment: You're trying to create an object of a new type (in this case String()) instead of the one you have.  Since there isn't a built-in way to do so, is going through hoops a "neater" way?  You could always write an extension method to do it.

Comment: @Yugal Meta-Knight's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868885/how-to-convert-string-to-string-array-in-vb-net/6874143#6874143) is the neatest thing I can imagine. Just add two braces `Print({s})`

Comment: Certainly.. 
Thumbs up.. to Meta-Knight !

Answer (score 3):

Use the `String.Split` method to split by "blank space". More details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

If character by character then write your own function to do that.

Try this code:

```
Dim input As String = "characters"
Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, "")
Console.Write("{")
For ctr As Integer = 0 to substrings.Length - 1
   Console.Write("'{0}'", substrings(ctr))
   If ctr < substrings.Length - 1 Then Console.Write(", ")
Next
Console.WriteLine("}")
' The example produces the following output:   
'    {'', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'e', 'r', 's', ''}
```

Using Regex, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx#Y2166.

Comment: No.. i don't want my string to split !!

Comment: So, I misunderstand your question... :(

Answer (score 2):

Can you just put that one string in to an array? My VB is rusty, but try this:

```
Dim arr(0) As String
arr(0) = str

func(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a VB expert, but this looks like the cleanest way to me:

```
func(New String() { str })
```

However, if that's not clean enough for you, you could use extension methods *either* specific to string:

```
func(str.ToStringArray)
```

*or* in a generic way:

```
func(str.ToSingleElementArray)
```

Here's the latter as an extension method:

```
<Extension> _
Public Shared Function ToSingleElementArray(Of T)(ByVal item As T) As T()
    Return New T() { item }
End Function
```

Comment: The cleanest way is `func( { str } )` as in [Meta-Knight's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868885/how-to-convert-string-to-string-array-in-vb-net/6874143#6874143)

Answer (score -1):

You mean like [String.ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx)?  Also, you can access the chars contained in the string [directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx).